# How do I create a Distribution list in an Exchange 2007 Public Folder using C#?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

The EWS API does not allow you to create a Distribution list if you are using Exchange 2007. Creating a ContactGroup is only supported in Exchange 2010.

How do you create a distribution list using C# in an Exchange Public Folder?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I would look at Exchange MAPI / CDO. Perhaps use this wrapper which is an excellent library: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/